# Steps for Syncing data by using chrome.storage.sync [Chrome Extension]

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm going to make my chrome extension to sync data by chrome.storage.sync
but how should I design the steps to sync data?
For example:
I insert data "A" "B" "C" using Chrome-1 and delete "B" using Chrome-2
then I login in to Chrome-3 I should see "A" "C" there(same as Chrome-1 Chrome-2)

how should I design program to make it?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: chrome.storage.sync does everything for you and it's not customizable. If you want to modify the behavior you'd have to implement it yourself, for example you can write modification history in a separate key and analyze it.